# Elasticsearch Filter Query by CIDR

Tags: elasticsearch, cidr

For example, how would you build an Elasticsearch query that filtered by documents containing an `ip` field that matches `192.168.100.14/24`?

```
{
    query: {
        filtered: {
            filter: {
                ???
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To clarify, the documents I am searching have a property that is indexed as an IP field, and I want to find all documents that have an IP that matches a CIDR mask (to be specified in a filter).

Answer (score 1):

try this if using ES 2.2 or later:

```
{"query": {"term" : {"<ip_field_name>" : "192.168.100.14/24"}}}
```

Comment: Query string query would look like this: <ip_field_name>:("192.168.1.0/24" "192.168.2.0/24")

Answer (score 0):

The elasticsearch type `ip` does not support that type of input.  Here is an example showing that it will fail:

## input

```
PUT index1
{
  "mappings": {
    "type1": {
      "properties": {
        "ip_addr": {
          "type": "ip"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


POST index1/type1
{
  ip_addr: "192.168.100.14/24"
}
```

## result

```
{
   "error": {
      "root_cause": [
         {
            "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
            "reason": "failed to parse [ip_addr]"
         }
      ],
      "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
      "reason": "failed to parse [ip_addr]",
      "caused_by": {
         "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
         "reason": "failed to parse ip [192.168.100.14/24], not a valid ip address"
      }
   },
   "status": 400
}
```

Instead, if you strip off the `/24` it will work properly.

Comment: I'm not talking about storing CIDRs as IPs, I'm talking about searching IPs using a CIDR mask. This led me to believe there must be some way to do it: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/7464